# UPS Tracking in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, powerquery

I am trying to use my Excel spreadsheet, which I use to keep track of my UPS shipments to update with the delivery timestamp.
I had used the format of:
http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=en_US&Requester=UPSHome&tracknum=[TRK_ID]&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes&ignore=&track.x=25&track.y=16

Where [TRK_ID] would reference the cell range of tracking numbers.
With this I could click on the link in the cell and be taken to a page with the tracking information.

I can't use the API, but want to just report back the delivery timestamp.  Maybe through Power Query?
Can I use Power Query to call the webpage and then extract the delivery confirmation timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look there's a clean UPS api to give you the delivery timestamp, but Power Query can parse it out of the HTML:

```
let
    PackageDelivery = (tracknum as text) as text => let
        WebText = Text.FromBinary(Web.Contents("http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest", [Query = [tracknum = tracknum]])),
        FromDeliveredOn = Text.Range(WebText, Text.PositionOf(WebText, "Delivered On:")),
        NextDD = Text.Range(FromDeliveredOn, Text.PositionOf(FromDeliveredOn, "<dd>") + 4, Text.PositionOf(FromDeliveredOn, "</dd>") - Text.PositionOf(FromDeliveredOn, "<dd>") - 4),
        Cleaned = Text.Clean(Text.Replace(Text.Replace(NextDD, "&nbsp;", " "), "#(lf)", " "))
    in
        Cleaned,
    Invoked = PackageDelivery("1ZE1W7530369979412")  //Replace with your tracking ID
in
    Invoked
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a hyperlink in the cell that will go to the relevant page with the [HYPERLINK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-fb589fd2-3bc8-4f56-bcac-6b8a79d64230). Example with a tracking number in A1:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=en_US&Requester=UPSHome&tracknum="&A1&"&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes&ignore=&track.x=25&track.y=16", "UPS Tracking page")
```

If you wanted to actually pull down the information, a VBA solution using something like a [XMLHttpRequest object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) would likely be your best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is user4039065's answer edited so that the link does not show if the reference cell is blank (just my personal preference):

```
=IF(**O18**<>"",HYPERLINK("http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=en_US&Requester=UPSHome&tracknum="&**O18**&"&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes&ignore=&track.x=25&track.y=16","Track"),"")
```

Change `O18` in both places in the formula to cell where the tracking number is located.